# How do I set build action for a new file?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

I added a new sql file to a folder. Now I want to change the properties of the file to be an embedded resource. When I right-click the file and go to Properties, it only shows the "General" section which is the name and location of the file.

[image: new file]

If I do the same for pre-existing files, they show build actions and other information which would allow me to change the type of resource it is.

[image: pre-existing file]

How do I get that to show up for a new file?

Answer (score 2):

We have created an issue in our tracker, it is obviously a bug. So you can track it there:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-31875